# Get auto increment ID after insert to use on another insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an insert query to add information from a PHP form into a table as well as upload an image. The form information and the image directory path are to be stored in separate tables. Here is what I am doing but it just does not seem to work.

```
//insert data from my form into DB, id is auto incremented so it's not in the insert.
$query = "INSERT INTO infotable (number, name, address, city, province, postal_code VALUES ('$facilityNumber', '$facilityName', '$facilityAddress', '$facilityCity', '$facilityProvince', '$facilityPostalCode' )";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//query used to get the id of the facility we had just entered
$getFacilityID = "SELECT id FROM infotable WHERE number = '$facilityNumber' AND name = '$facilityName' "
    . "AND address = '$facilityAddress' AND city = '$facilityCity'";

$queryData = mysqli_query($dbc, $getFacilityID);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryData);

//attempt to echo out the value of the ID (this is always empty)
echo $row['id'];

//insert image into image table + id from infotable ... I haven't even got to test this yet.
$imageQuery = "INSERT INTO photo (id, photo, photo_desc)"
            . "VALUES ($row['id'], $facilityPhoto, $facilityPhotoDesc)";

mysqli_query($dbc, $imageQuery);
```

Comment: *"I haven't even got to test this yet."* - Test it and show us the error you'll be getting `mysqli_query($dbc, $imageQuery)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`. You're also mixing MySQL APIs `mysql_fetch_assoc()` <= can't use that, add an `i`. Plus, do add the missing `$` in `query =...` in your question, if it's a typo.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php -- Also, you seem to be mixing up mysql and mysqli.  Make sure you're always using one or the other (preferably mysqli)

Comment: Sorry yeah I have been using mysqli just typo's, should be all fixed

Comment: You have answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the auto-increment id, just use the built-in `mysqli_insert_id` function:

```
$getFacilityID = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);
```

Your code could then be re-written as below:

```
//insert data from my form into DB, id is auto incremented so it's not in the insert.
$query = "INSERT INTO infotable (number, name, address, city, province, postal_code VALUES ('$facilityNumber', '$facilityName', '$facilityAddress', '$facilityCity', '$facilityProvince', '$facilityPostalCode' )";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//query used to get the id of the facility we had just entered
$getFacilityID = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

//attempt to echo out the value of the ID (this is always empty)
echo $getFacilityID;

//insert image into image table + id from infotable ... I haven't even got to test this yet.
$imageQuery = "INSERT INTO photo (id, photo, photo_desc)"
        . "VALUES ($getFacilityID, $facilityPhoto, $facilityPhotoDesc)";

mysqli_query($dbc, $imageQuery);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I was unaware that this function existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need `mysqli_insert_id` to solve your problem.

See the procedural example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware this function existed!